# Password Field Length Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have written a custom hasher for the passwords and it returns a hashed password length of 148. But Django seems to limit the length of the password in the SQL table to 128 by default. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use a custom user model that overrides the password field:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model for details.

As an alternative workaround, you can use a third party applicaton called django-primate: https://github.com/aino/django-primate#alternative-password-hashing